# Element with popover and tooltip

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

In a large form, I'm using popovers to display error messages from the validation (I know, not best practice).

Now, I also want to add tooltips to display detailed explanation of the input.

However, using both, the `tooltip` and the `popover` directive (and their associated `-trigger` and `-placement` directives), the behavior is odd/buggy: Both, tooltip and popover are placed based on the `popover-placement` directive (ignoring the `tooltip-placement`) - and display the text provided for the popover.

```
<button class="btn btn-default"
    popover="Popover" popover-trigger="mouseenter" popover-placement="right" 
    tooltip="Tooltip" tooltip-trigger="mouseenter" tooltip-placement="top" >
Label</button>
```

See this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/gxYpvDKUw43pC7nE5aKa?p=preview).

Any idea how to make this work?

Comment: The popover directive calls the tooltip provider to generate the popover element, so you are essentially trying to have 2 tooltips on the same element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They actually infact use the same placement function.

From the docs on popover:

> The popover directive also supports various default configurations through the **`$tooltipProvider`**. See the tooltip section for more information.

Meaning if you had the following code:

```js
app.config(['$tooltipProvider', function($tooltipProvider){
  $tooltipProvider.options({
    'placement': 'right'
  });
}]);
```

It would change the default for both tooltips and popovers.

Best I can think of is it have some sort of wrapper around the element so you can do each in turn.

```html
<button class="btn btn-default sampleBtn"
  popover="Popover" popover-trigger="mouseenter" popover-placement="right">
  <span tooltip="Tooltip" tooltip-trigger="mouseenter"  tooltip-placement="top">
    Tooltip + Popover
  </span>
</button>
```

#### [Demo in Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/RaUnUeruZLEGKMIBMSQZ?p=preview)

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

A very Simple Way..Just Make a parent Span for the button and attach those properties with that Span. I have Some Code for that too

```
<span title="Popover title" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-content="Some content in Popover on bottom">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip"  data-placement="right" title="Tooltip on right">Tooltip on right</button>
</span>
```

Here is the JS Fiddle for that too

http://jsfiddle.net/h75k1fzj/